# zend form not working when calling to multiple page

Tags: zend-framework

I have a controller action

```
public function pagedetailAction(){

    $id  = $this->_getParam('id',0);
    $detail = new Application_Model_Page();
    $this->view->detail = $detail->findArr($id);
    //CALLING FORM WITH OTHER CONTENTS
    $form = new Application_Form_Request();
    $this->view->form = $form;

}
```

To process the form I have this function

```
public function submitrequestAction(){

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) {


            $newsadd = new Application_Model_Request($formData);
            $newsadd->set_ID(null);
            $newsadd->save();

            $this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage(array('success'=>'Message Sent'));
            $this->_redirect('/index/frontmsg');
        } else {
            $form->populate($formData);
        }

    }

}
```

when i click submit i get the error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: form in E:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox1\application\controllers\IndexController.php on line 84

Fatal error: Call to a member function isValid() on a non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox1\application\controllers\IndexController.php on line 84
```

Please help me so that I can post values to database via this form. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
 public function submitrequestAction(){

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $form = new Application_Form_Request();//added this
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) {


            $newsadd = new Application_Model_Request($formData);
            $newsadd->set_ID(null);
            $newsadd->save();

            $this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage(array('success'=>'Message Sent'));
            $this->_redirect('/index/frontmsg');
        } else {
            $form->populate($formData);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This function neither validate data nor send data to database

Comment: could you check whether form is validated or not by putting the echo? and see is there any issue with model?

Comment: The main problem is with data validation if i remove this if clause in $form->isValid($formData) , then data is posted but without validation

Comment: So get the errors using getErrors() from form and display it to user.

Answer (score 0):

Add $form initialization to your submitrequestAction:

```
$form = new Application_Form_Request();
```